# Sort after xsl copy-of statement

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

In this [screenprint](https://lschamba.home.xs4all.nl/SO_ResultScreen.jpg)  you see the marked fields are not sorted.

Here is the [sourcefile](https://lschamba.home.xs4all.nl/SO_configuration.xml)

This is the [xslt](https://lschamba.home.xs4all.nl/SO_lookuptables.xsl) 
I only can use V1.0:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <lookupTables>
            <xsl:for-each select="/XML/lookupType">
                <xsl:variable name="label" select="lookupTypeLabel"/>
                <xsl:element name="lookupTable">
                    <xsl:attribute name="label"><xsl:value-of 
                    select="$label"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                       <decisionTrees>
                        <xsl:copy-of 
select="/XML/decisionTree[businessObjectId/@Type = $label]"/>
                       </decisionTrees>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </lookupTables>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

When you execute above xslt this [output](https://lschamba.home.xs4all.nl/SO_output.xml) is shown.

The xml coming from here `<xsl:copy-of 
    select="/XML/decisionTree[businessObjectId/@Type = $label]"/>` needs to be sorted on userDefinedField/fieldValue
Is there a way to do this sort after the copy-of statement in the same xslt?